# Annoying message when opening windows from Python on OS X 10.8

Tags: python, macos, osx-mountain-lion

Whenever I run a Python script that opens any kind of window on OS X 10.8, whether it's a GLUT window or a QT one or anything else, I get a message that looks like this:

```
2013-09-11 14:36:53.321 Python[3027:f07] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/0x/25_70mj17tb1ypm1c_js8jd40000gq/T/org.python.python.savedState
```

I use python2.7 installed via MacPorts.

This is a minor annoyance, but I'm curious to know what the message means, and whether there's anything I can do to prevent it. Is it due to a misconfiguration of my system, or does everyone get this?

Comment: It seems that only Mac users get this and it can occur on a variety of programs - the issue is the setting on the Restore on restart flag for a given process.

Comment: @SteveBarnes thanks for the information. Is the "restore on restart" flag something I can change, to stop this message coming up for Python scripts?

Comment: Possibly - I am not a Mac expert but it seems that several people are having problems with this.

Comment: It appears that typing the Terminal command `defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO` gets rid of the warning. I will use it for a bit and post that as an answer if it doesn't cause any problems. (Or you can post it if you care about the rep.) Many thanks for giving me a hint that helped me solve it.

Comment: (visitors to this question may wish to note that the highest-voted answer was posted shortly *after* my own answer that says the same thing.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Answering my own question, with thanks to @Steve Barnes for giving me a hint. It seems this problem can be solved with the terminal command

```
$ defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO
```

In the comments, Greg Coladonato reports that, in 2020, running Python 3, this may need to be changed to

```
$ defaults write org.python.python3 ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO
```

I am not sure exactly how this command operates, but having done it some time ago I have observed no ill effects.

Note however, that another user has pointed out that this can cause a bug with python 3.4 on mountain lion where tkinter dialogs do not close when a button is pressed as one would expect.

```
$ defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

will undo the command if you experience problems. (Replacing `org.python.python` with `org.python.python3` if needed.)

Comment: thanks a lot, you made my day! I actually had the tkinter problem for ages on yosemite and el capitan (in both py2 and py3), now it's completely solved with the first command (with `NO`) you pointed out.

Comment: On my python3.7 (of forgotten provenance) the former works and the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 55):

The correct command to run is:

```
defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO
```

This message appears due to the "application resume" feature in newer versions of OS X. Clearly, this isn't a useful feature for most Python programs (in my case, plotting data with matplotlib), so we can just turn it off with the above command.

For more information on what `defaults write` is actually doing, check out the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html).

Comment: Thanks! I was getting this error when trying to import the cocos library (cocos2d) in case that helps anyone.

Comment: this worked for me, not sure why it came up at the first place, it was not showing up earlier

Comment: In 2020, running Python3, I needed to use `org.python.python3` for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

When running an anaconda python distribution, a slightly different write is needed:

`defaults write com.continuum.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO`

Answer (score 1):

I am running wxpython 4.1.1 with pyenv and sandbox everything with virtual environments.    I am running python 3.9.x The option:

`defaults write org.python.python3 ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO`

did not work for me.  But,

`defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO`

did