# Tk open window issue/bug

Tags: python, tkinter

If I type the following in the interpreter it works like a charm:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
fh = open(askopenfilename(), 'r')
```

However, if I write/save/run a script with exactly the same commands, though it works (kind of like expected) the open window goes blank and remains on screen (after opening the selected file) and stays on top of everything.

As a result I need to click on the Python icon again in order for the window to close. At one point this stopped happening, but when I ran a script once without the `Tk().withdraw()` command the problem re-emerged.

I am running OSX Mavericks. If there is no way to fix the bug, is there any command in Python I can implement that closes this window?

Comment: I had the same problem. It actually started when I was looking for a way to get rid of an annoying warning. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733965/annoying-message-when-opening-windows-from-python-on-os-x-10-8) post. I tried the suggested solution and started experiencing the behavior you describe. I undid the command by entering `defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES` in terminal. It doesn't seem like the best solution but it works.

Answer (score 2):

See the accepted answer to this question [When do I need to call mainloop in a Tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/tkinter-when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop).  You normally need to call `Tk.mainloop()` to start the event loop processing for Tk.  But when you are running in the interactive interpreter, Python calls the Tk event processor for you, otherwise you would not be able to use Tkinter in the interactive interpreter as easily.