# ApplePersistenceIgnoreState error, started just after wxPython installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, homebrew

I'm trying to test some PsychoPy code on a Mac, but I couldn't import a key module because I didn't have wxPython installed. I installed wxPython using Homebrew, which said:

```
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
   mkdir -p /Users/noahsilbert/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/noahsilbert/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

So I did, and now IPython is giving me the following error, and I cannot figure out what's triggering it:

```
2015-12-29 11:20:17.850 python[5040:855441] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/vm/851b53f57ql7tsx_jjpltblh0000gn/T/com.continuum.python.savedState
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733965/annoying-message-when-opening-windows-from-python-on-os-x-10-8/21567601), and it looks like I could try this as a solution:

```
$ defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO
```

Since I don't totally understand what this does, I'm a bit worried that this could cause other problems. Ultimately, I still can't get the PsychoPy code working on my computer, so I would, I think, prefer to undo the instructions that Homebrew gave me to put its site-packages in my Python sys.path, but I'm not sure how to do this. The [`site` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) isn't giving me an obvious solution, so any help would be appreciated.

Is there an easy way to undo the Homebrew instructions? Should I just try the `defaults write` command?

I'm using the Anaconda scientific Python installation on El Capitan, for what it's worth.

Comment: Well, this seems to have had nothing at all to do with Homebrew, wxPython, or PsychoPy. The possible solution I mentioned didn't work, but I figured out that it was only happening when I tried to import pyplot from matplotlib. I installed matplotlib 1.4 instead of 1.5, and the error went away.

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon. The error appears again the first time I try to plot something. This is deeply annoying.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22467012/1112283. Basically, you have to run the `defaults` command. Actually, `import wx; app = wx.App()` triggered the message (which gets called from `psychopy`). Try if this works for you (it did for me).