# ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, qmake

This is not a duplicate of

[Annoying message when opening windows from Python on OS X 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733965/annoying-message-when-opening-windows-from-python-on-os-x-10-8)

nor

[ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743664/applepersistenceignorestate-existing-state-will-not-be-touched-new-state-will)

On macOS 12.6 M1 Mac using Qt Creator with the following project:

project.pro

```
QT      += core gui widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I get:

```
2023-02-21 19:03:27.856 project[1046:8402] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/wg/4020zfmd3n7gk7_7zr_rp6fw0000gn/T/com.yourcompany.project.savedState
```

Renaming project.pro to project1.pro fix the problem.

But what's the problem of naming it project.pro?

Tried removing the build artifacts and rebuilding, even restart machine, moving project to another folder, problem persists.